# Google play market Разрешения с высоким уровнем риска

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-permissions

Одна из функция моей программы на OS Android, это определять входящий/исходящий звонок. Для этого в файле Manifest я прописал следующие разрешения :

```
android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG
```

Эти разрешения Google отнес к **разрешениям с высоким уровнем риска**. Сам google предоставляет какую-то поверхностную [информацию](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10208820). Просит заполнить какую-то непонятную декларацию, которую я ни разу не прошел. При этом из-за этого можно получить бан. Кто-то написал, что google сделал это для того что бы отфильтровать свой рынок от грязи и всего прочего.

Так же я видел, что можно сделать отдельный модуль, который закачивается после установки программы. Сам я этого не делал, так как немного страшновато сделать что-то не правильно!

Как можно решить эту проблему, кроме как убрать функцию определения входящего/исходящего звонков с программы?

Кто знает, как нужно правильно заполнить декларацию, чтобы получить одобрение во время обновления от googple play market. Поделитесь инфой, PLEASE. Объясните пошагово что, куда и как! Буду очень рад и благодарен!

Comment: Ну так там же есть и [ссылка](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102) с пошаговой инструкцией. В чем проблема с заполнением?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov спасибо за внимание. Я исправил свой вопрос. Проблема в том что я получаю отказы. Первые разы заполнял по инструкции, которую предоставляет google play console, не прошло. Потом начал заполнять методом научного тыка, тоже не прошло. Что делать? Убирать эту функцию?